# Tool for integration testing to replace Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing

Now I'm using cucumber, but I find it a little oververbosity. I'm not going to show cucumber futures to somebody without Ruby knowledge. So now I'm thinking that it isn't necessary to duplicate integration test in human-readable text and in step definitions. It makes me to do useless job.

I'm in the middle of my way to something more geeky than cucumber. Something like rspec integration but with power no less than cucumber power.

Could you advice some tool for integration testing for my purposes?

Comment: rspec / capybara, I dislike the verbosity and the false easiness of cucumber

Comment: Please, no discussions on SO. Maybe you can rephrase your question so that it is a) about code and b) can be answered directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RSpec feature specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) are fairly analogous to Cucumber integration tests. This requires the [Capybara gem](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

Moving your tests back to RSpec keep them more code-like, and you remove the extra step of needing to parse gherkin. This is a good approach if you don't really need to be sharing the specs with non-technical folks.

Thoughbot has a post that illustrates an interesting actor-based approach to feature specs: [End-to-end testing with RSpec integration tests and Capybara](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33771089985/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara).

The upcoming [Rails 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/bigg2/) book describes how to do feature specs in great detail. There is a [GitHub repo for the code referenced in the book](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee-v2) (the sample app is a project-tracking system) if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Spinach](http://codegram.github.com/spinach/) :)! I have the feeling it is exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion, you should also consider [turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip), though it seems very similar to spinach; deciding factor for me for choosing turnip was the seeming lack of placeholders in Spinach, which I have a hard time understanding.